# in PostgreSQL how to write Random

Tags: postgresql

I'm converting oracle to PostgreSQL while converting i'm getting error like `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "W_SL"` error please help me to solve this error.

```
W_SL := random.string('x', 35);
```

Comment: 1) Postgres does not have anything like `random.string()` 2) The error  is happening because you can only assign using `:=` inside a function, specifically `plpgsql` AFAIK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to generate random string you'll need to create a function in your postgresql. For example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION random_string_pavel(int)
RETURNS text
AS $$ 
  SELECT array_to_string(
    ARRAY (
      SELECT substring(
        '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ' 
        FROM (random() *36)::int FOR 1)
      FROM generate_series(1, $1) ), '' ) 
$$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

Here's more: https://www.simononsoftware.com/random-string-in-postgresql/

Comment: sir i have  declared W_SL in varchar and am getting error like this syntax error at or near "SELECT"
LINE 15:  SELECT array_to_string(

Comment: You can simply change type function returns (second line) from text to varchar or cast it like SELECT random_string_pavel(10)::varchar;